# Uploaded pictures and videos for Xamarin / Asp-net Core application

Tags: azure, xamarin, asp.net-core, storage

I am building a mobile app using Xamarin for the front-end and I am using asp.net core for the back-end deployed on azure. The user can make posts or ads or see other posts of other users. He can  upload some photos and some small videos attached to each post.

My questions what are the best alternatives to host the uploaded pictures and videos for similar applications.

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not entirely sure what you mean, I think the best answer would be Azure Storage, since you're alread in Azure and that's _the_ storage solution over there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

There's a pretty good information on how to set it up using  [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/storage/azure-storage).

Also, a [Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/AzureStorage/).